# Рисование невыпуклого многоугольника со свечением

Tags: алгоритм, графика

Подскажите алгоритм (можно и реализацию,желательно на C++) рисования многоугольника с регулируемыми мягкими краями.

Все что дано: координаты точек, последовательным соединением которых получаем многоугольник(возможно невыпуклый), квадратное изображение, для которого отсутствует возможность рисования каких либо примитивов. Можно изменять лишь байты, отвечающие за каналы пикселей в этом изображении.

Пример результата: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чисто математический подход оказался слишком ресурсоемким. Пытался для каждой стороны(отрезка) многоугольника определить 
1. с какой стороны относительно этого отрезка находится пиксель(точки расположены последовательно так, чтобы они соединялись линиями по часовой стрелке, то есть справа от отрезка всегда находилась внутренняя часть фигуры)
2. определить, может ли падать перпендикуляр от моей точки(пикселя) к отрезку
3. если может и 1 пункт выполняется, тогда пиксель возможно находится внутри фигуры. И если так работает для каждой стороны(в чем я не уверен, так как тестировал на примере трех сторон(только с выпуклой фигурой), тогда точка внутри
4. иначе находим точку пересечения отрезка и перпендикуляра(в случае выполнения пункта 2), перпендикулярно падающей от точки, находим расстояние - это и будет ответом, определяющим, на сколько нужно окрашивать пиксель, чтобы сделать плавный переход от краев. В другом случае, определять расстояние от ближней точки, образующей этот отрезок.

Вот такое оочень громоздкое получилось описание, а реализация еще требовательнее к ресурсам, даже не хочется смотреть, что где подкорректировать можно((

Comment: Может быть, покажите желаемый результат? Например, для случая [простейшего самопересекающегся четырёхугольника](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t795s.png).

Comment: дополнил, думаю, что самопересекающийся не понадобится)

Comment: Мягкость края надо менять динамически или 1 раз отрисовать и все?  Многоугольник один или тоже меняется динамически? Размеры какие, 100 или 1000 пикселей? Какие ограничения по скорости работы?

Comment: А чем не подойдёт просто нарисовать многоугольник с заливкой и жёсткими краями, и размыть по Гауссу? Gaussian blur — быстрая штука.

Comment: @Ni55aN: Вот ваш рисунок [с жёсткими краями](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez7c0.png), и [то же после блюра](http://i.stack.imgur.com/laOfu.png).

Comment: Думаю, наиболее быстрым будет способ, который применяется в большинстве графических библиотек: 1) триангулировать многоугольник; 2) нарисовать все треугольники без размытия по алгоритму Брезенхэма; 3) проехаться по всему битмапу фильтром Гаусса

Comment: @Krom Stern, один раз все отрисовать. В пределах одного изображения может быть несколько многоугольников. По скорости как таковых ограничений нет, но чем быстрее - тем лучше - так как таким образом хочу генерировать маски для чанков террейна в opengl, которые динамически добавляются

Comment: Может быть тогда попробовать рендер-в-текстуру и блюр на GPU?

Comment: не уверен, возможно это отразится на fps

Comment: в данный момент на этапе заливки контура получаю следующее: http://jsfiddle.net/j8x4w4xL/2/ Для каждой строки прохожу по пикселям начиная слева. Определяю попадание на контур, и меняю флаг inside, таким образом при попадании на контур как при входе в него, так и при выходе меняется состояние заливать/не заливать. Но вот проблема в том, что на краях контура засчитывает пиксели которые расположены на краях отрезков

Comment: А почему не Гаусс? Будет всяко быстрее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/j8x4w4xL/10/) что получилось

1. Для каждой строки определил точки пересечения со сторонами многоугольника
2. Отсортировал их по `x` координате
3. Каждая пара этих координат и является началом и концом горизонтального отрезка, поэтому рисуем их

UPD:
4. для размытия краев применяется прямой blur ко всему изображению, что не очень продуктивно, поэтому лучше применять Distance Transform (кажется, этот метод применяется в графических редакторах для генерирования теней